# Modifying a number value in text

Tags: awk

I have a text coming in as

```
A1:B2.C3.D4.E5
A2:B7.C10.D0.E9
A0:B1.C9.D4.E8
```

I wonder how to change it as

```
A1:B2.C1.D4.E5
A2:B7.C8.D0.E9
A0:B1.C7.D4.E8
```

using Awk. First problem is multiple delimiter. Second is, how to get the C-Value and Decrement by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk solution:

```
$ awk -F"." '{$2=substr($2,0,1)""substr($2,2)-2;}1' OFS="." file
A1:B2.C1.D4.E5
A2:B7.C8.D0.E9
A0:B1.C7.D4.E8
```

Comment: Looks like yours is solaris. Use nawk in place of awk.

Comment: Yes. Found it later that this works using nawk. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk rather than nawk as it has more POSIX functionality. Your awks of choice should be, in order: gawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, nawk. Never use /usr/bin/awk (aka old, broken awk).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering wether awk regexp would do the job, but apparently, awk cannot capture pattern. This is why I suggest perl solution:

```
$ cat data.txt 
A1:B2.C3.D4.E5
A2:B7.C10.D0.E9
A0:B1.C9.D4.E8
$ perl -pe 's/C([0-9]+)/"C" . ($1-2)/ge;' data.txt
A1:B2.C1.D4.E5
A2:B7.C8.D0.E9
A0:B1.C7.D4.E8
```

Comment: awk CAN capture the string that matches an RE, just not in as brief a code as perl or sed. See match()/substr() and gensub().

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I probably would have done this using the `substr()` function like Guru has shown:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="." } { $2 = substr($2,0,1) substr($2,2) - 2 }1' file
```

I do also like Aif's answer using Perl probably just a little more. Shorter is sweeter, isn't it? However, `GNU awk` can capture pattens. Here's how:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="." } match($2, /(C)(.*)/, a) { $2 = a[1] a[2] - 2}1' file
```

Comment: +1 for the solutions. wrt the "shorter is sweeter" statement, though - brevity is not a desirable quality of software, conciseness is. perl solutions are often brief but rarely clear so they're usually not concise.